# Joint probability density of recursively defined random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, induction

> Q:  $X_1,\cdots,X_N$ are recursively defined random variables,
>   $$
> X_n = \underset{\color{blue}{\text{Taylor series like part}}}{\underbrace{X_{n-1} + f(X_{n-1})\delta+ (X_n-X_{n-1})f'(X_{n-1})\delta}}+\underset{\color{red}{\text{Noise}}}{\underbrace{\;\;W_n\;\;}}
> $$
>   where $X_0=0$ is a constant, $\delta$ and $\beta$ are also constants and $W_1,\cdots,W_N$ are iid $N(0,\beta\delta)$. Show that the joint density of $(X_1,\cdots, X_N)$ is given by,
>   $$
> C\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^NV_n\right)
> $$
>   where $C$ is a normalizing constant and $V_n$ are defined as,
>   $$
> V_n = \frac{\left(x_n-x_{n-1} -\delta f(x_{n-1})  -(x_n-x_{n-1})\delta f'(x_{n-1})\right)^2}{2\beta\delta}
> $$
>   with $x_0 = 0$.

Attempt: 
$$
X_1 = \frac{f(0)\delta + W_1}{1-\delta f'(0)}
$$
is a normal random variable with mean $\frac{f(0)\delta}{1-\delta f'(0)}$ and variance $\frac{\beta\delta}{(1-\delta f'(0))^2}$ and therefore,
$$
V_1 = \frac{\left(x_1 -\frac{\delta f(0)}{1-\delta f'(0)}\right)^2}{\frac{2\beta\delta}{(1-\delta f'(0))^2}} = \frac{\left(x_1-x_{0} -\delta f(x_{0})  -(x_1-x_{0})\delta f'(x_{0})\right)^2}{2\beta\delta}
$$
The numerator of $V_n$ mimics the Taylor series like part. But I don't know how to proceed to the density of $(X_1, X_2)$ or use induction.

Source: [Implicit sampling for particle filters - Chorin and Tu](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/106/41/17249.full.pdf) (page - $1$, section: sampling by interpolation and iteration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the case when $X_1=x_1$. Let $\varepsilon$ be a small positive number and $f_X$ denote probability density of $X$.

\begin{align}
X_2 &= \frac{x_1+f(x_1)\delta+x_1f'(x_1)\delta + W_2}{1-\delta f'(x_1)}\\
\implies& p(X_2\in B(x_2, \varepsilon)|X_1=x_1) = p(W_2\in B(x_2-x_1-f(x_1)\delta-(x_2-x_1)f'(x_1)\delta, \varepsilon) )\\
\implies& \int_{x_2-\varepsilon}^{x_2+\varepsilon}f_{X_2|X_1}(\tau|x_1)\,d\tau=\int_{x_2-\varepsilon}^{x_2+\varepsilon}C'\exp\left(-\frac{(\tau-x_1-f(x_1)\delta-(\tau-x_1)f'(x_1)\delta )^2}{2\beta\delta}\right)\,d\tau\\
\implies& f_{X_2|X_1}(x_2|x_1)\times2\varepsilon+O(\varepsilon^2) = C'\exp\left(-\frac{(x_2-x_1-f(x_1)\delta-(x_2-x_1)f'(x_1)\delta )^2}{2\beta\delta}\right)\times2\varepsilon+O(\varepsilon^2)\\
\implies& f_{X_2|X_1}(x_2|x_1) = C'\exp\left(-V_2\right)\\
\implies& f_{X_2,X_1}(x_2,x_1) = f_{X_2|X_1}(x_2|x_1)f_{X_1}(x_1)=C''\exp(-(V_1+V_2))
\end{align}
And similarly we can progress to $f_{X_n,\cdots,X_1}(x_n, \cdots, x_1)$.